# Dictionary record is truncated when printing

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, floating-point

I have a dictionary containing some floating-point values.

When I print the dictionary as is, I get these values printed in full accuracy.

However, when I attempt to print each value separately, I get them truncated.

A simple coding example to illustrate the problem:

```
d = {'x': 0.010000000000000231}
print d      # outputs {'x': 0.010000000000000231}
print d['x'] # outputs 0.01
```

Now, of course I can solve this using `format`, i.e., in the example above:

```
print '{:.18f}'.format(d['x']) # outputs 0.010000000000000231
```

However, I wish to avoid this kind of solution.

First and foremost, because I do not know the exact precision required for each entry in the dictionary. Second, because I prefer to avoid the type of cumbersome coding, which involves specifying print format of every field to begin with.

In other words, I want to do something like:

```
print 'x = {}'.format(d['x'])
```

Or:

```
print 'x =',d['x']
```

And get the value of `d['x']` printed in its full precision.

Why does the Python interpreter chooses different print formats for `d` and for `d['x']`, and what approach can I take here in order to achieve my purpose?

Comment: You could use the `decimal` module - https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is a difference between what is printed when the `__str__` method is invoked vs when the `__repr__` is invoked.

An example:

```
In [816]: print 0.010000000000000231
0.01

In [817]: print repr(0.010000000000000231)
0.010000000000000231
```

The reason for this difference is because `str` attempts to truncate the number in python2.

This is changed in python3, and the `str` and `repr` behave consistently.

Comment: Great, so encapsulating every `print` with `repr` would solve the problem then?

Answer (score 1):

> When I print the dictionary as is, I get these values printed in full accuracy.

No, not really. Example (note the different last digit):

```
>>> d = {'x': 0.010000000000000232}
>>> print d
{'x': 0.010000000000000233}
```

And neither is the actual full accuracy of what `d['x']` is:

```
>>> print ('%.2000f' % d['x']).rstrip('0')
0.01000000000000023266111259800936750252731144428253173828125
```

What you get when you print the dictionary is the `repr` string. What you get when you print just the float is the `str` string:

```
>>> print d['x']
0.01
>>> print str(d['x'])
0.01
>>> print repr(d['x'])
0.010000000000000233
```

So just use `repr` if you want the same output as in the printing of the dictionary.

I think the reason is that when you print a number, it's likely to be shown to an end user. And a value like 0.010000000000000231 in reality (i.e., not artificially entered like you did) is more likely the result of imprecision of a computer's calculation and the real value really is 0.01 instead. Like when you made calculations with prices in dollars, so 0.01 means 1 cent. So it makes more sense to show that to the end user instead of 0.010000000000000231.

But when you print a dictionary or other larger structure, that's likely *not* shown to an end user but more likely a developer wanting it as debug output. And for the developer, it's important to get a value that "accurately" represents the stored value, not a prettified version.